# Runtime error in codechef

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not here to ask any solution. Please keep in mind. I am tring to solve a problem April challange. My solution gives correct output when i run it using python over my computer but it gives runtime error when i submit the code. I dont want to give the whole code as its ongoing contest.

I am sure i have taken care of all the boundary conditions.
Here is what i am trying to do. Simply i am traversing the array and doing some operations as given in the problem.

problem link(if u want to see ranges of integers used)

http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/ADIGIT

```
    n,t=map(int,raw_input().split())
    a=raw_input()
    a=[int(s) for s in a]

    while(t):

        //do something
        t=t-1
```

Comment: That code is fine. Your problem is somewhere else. Maybe you want to write a random test case generator to find your bug

Comment: I think problem is somewhere else.i will try.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time runtime error occurs when you try to access the invalid memory or declare a huge bunch of memory.